# Build *.java files generated as part of build in ant

Tags: java, ant

My ant has:

```
<target name="createJava">
   <javac ... />
</target>
<target name="build" depends="createJava, compile" />
```

The createJava task adds a few java files under src root.
However, main build target always compile except them. How can I add java files created in the middle of build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the files for "compile" has been set before "createJava" and no updated before "compile".

Comment: You're right! After compiling it, I added <var name="src" unset="true"/><property name="src" location="srcdir"/> and worked. But now, the created files are not present at the time it builds. adding sleep does not help. without last build, it creates java files well. with continuous tasks, seems there is a synchronization issue.

Comment: Check paths _src_ and _dest_ for all your operations.

Comment: I've finally figured it out. I was confused by my unit-test routine which creates java files as well. I should have added <java ..> after <javac ...> so as to compile and run. Thank you for your help. Your advice helped me to exclude other possibilities. :)